# How to execute commands WHILE taking input?

Tags: c++

How can i execute some commands while waiting for an input?

---

Something like this:

```
while(/*taking input*/) {
    sleep(15);
    cout<<"You still there?";

    //...     
}
```

---

So it asks for the input, but while it waits for ENTER to be pressed it executes commands.
Is it possible?

**Edit**:
Thanks for all the suggestions :)

Comment: You can delegate work into another thread.

Comment: multithreading. Although if you print something to console WHILE user is typing, things can get messy/confusing for the user.

Comment: As I said, I'm still a newbie. Thanks anyways, I'll figure it out :)

Comment: Multithreading is way too big a cannon for this tiny  problem. A simple non-blocking I/O multiplexing loop should do just fine.

Comment: That was just an example. I want to use it for a chat, so while the 1st thread is used to send messages, the 2nd is used to receive messages :)

Comment: @ImmortalFire : If it involves networking, that's an even better reason to use Kerrek SB's suggestion instead of threads.

Comment: `c` or `c++` ? It rarely can be both. In this example possible solutions would differ quite much.

Comment: @ImmortalFire: If that's for a chat, avoid multithreading. Asynchronous IO or some kind of message-based behavior.

Comment: @luk32: his example has `cout <<` so that's c++.

Comment: @luk32 : The broad outlines of the solution would be the same WRT this question.

Comment: I asked for a suggestion. I didn't know if there was a similar function in C++, or C, or both. As I said, I'm still a newbie..

Comment: @goldilocks Sorry for my impudence but whats WRT XD. I don't like over tagging questions. I would even go as far as saying there is like 10+ comments with no real answer because of it. People just don't know what example to give as an attempt to answering. Why there is no immediate idea with code that I can up-vote? Dear OP, IMO your question is on the borderline of closing according to the guidelines by showing no attempt to solve it by yourself and broadness. Personally I would not be that harsh, but I would like it to be more concrete on the problem and system you are working with.

Comment: @luk32: you can edit to remove the C tag, I've gone ahead and done this. WRT, more commonly written w.r.t., means "with respect to".

Comment: @user7116 Thanks for lighting this up for me! As to removing `c` tag, using `cout` as the only premise to assume OP is interested in `c++` and not `c` is not enough. To me he should specify at least what language or compiler he uses, or if it does not matter. Well, after all, IMO  it is way easier to answer now! I hope everybody's happier.

Comment: Check my C solution for your problem and please put the C tag back :)

Comment: @luk32: there is only one correct choice when `cout` is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using C++11 threading facilities, you can simply spawn a "worker" thread that does the work while you wait for the input.

`std::async` is an easy way to asynchronously get a result of an operation; your problem description isn't very precise, so I don't know what else I might add here.

It can be done without threading, but then you would need an asynchrounous access to the input, which in general isn't cross-platform.

After Martin's comment, I actually see the problem with a greater clarity; in this case, your best bet is probably to look for more abstracted IO APIs, which will provide nonblocking input, or create your own based on OS-specific API.

Comment: No, threads don't help for this kind of work. I/O is blocking and serialised. Spawning threads won't help output stuff while waiting for input. C++ simply does not provide for this at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to achieve your objective:

1. Multithreading
2. Asynchronous IO

For the use case you mentioned (a chat), I'd recommend to look into the second option. You may want to have a look at the documentation for [boost asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), which contains an example for a chat client and server.

Answer (score 1):

You want to spawn another thread to run in parallel with the thread's that's waiting for i/o (input from stdin in this case).  Run whatever it is you want to do while waiting for i/o in that spawned thread. Have a look at [Boost threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you allow to add something outside your segment, it will work:

```
[wolf@Targaryen]:~$ cat main.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s;
  while( getline(cin, s) and s != "" ) {
    cout << "You still there?" << endl;
  }
}
[wolf@Targaryen]:~$ r
adb
You still there?
sfcetgw
You still there?
wefew
You still there?

[wolf@Targaryen]:~$
```